# How to debug UI in iMessage Extension?

Tags: swift3, ios10, ios-extensions, imessage-extension

I am developing iMessage Extension, but i am facing some UI issues. But I am not able to debug UI as like iOS Application.

As extension run on `com.apple.MobileSMS`(iMessage App Container).
So, is there any way to debug UI of iMessage Extension ?

Comment: have you found option to debug the UI in iMessage

Comment: No, Still not found.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no option to Debug UI hierarchy in iMessage till
>   **Xcode-8.1** . It shows the black spaces in the UI while tap to **DEBUG** iMessage UI .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of now Xcode 8.3.2 Doesn't support View Hierarchy Debugging for extensions in general (At least from my experience)

However there is this Software called [Reveal by Itty Bitty Apps](https://revealapp.com/%20Reveal%20By%20Itty%20Bitty%20Apps)

This is probably even better than Xcode's native View Hierarchy debugger since it also displays additional detailed stuff like broken constraint, ambiguous width and height and it can also point out at which view it has these issues, and you can also change view properties while in runtime.

Give it a try.